# mapに与える&を.（ドット）で繋ぎたい

Tags: ruby

```
class Hoge
  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize(value)
    @foo = Foo.new(value)
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end

values = [
  Hoge.new(1),
  Hoge.new(2)
]


p values.map{|hoge| hoge.foo.value} #=> 問題なし
p values.map(&:foo.value) #=> エラー
```

> undefined method `value' for :foo:Symbol (NoMethodError)

サンプルソースは上記のとおりです。
エラーが起きているものの行の上の行と同等の動きをすると想定していますが、文法的に認識してくれずエラーのようです。正しい書き方はありますか？

Comment: `.` で繋いでいませんが、`p (values.map &:foo).map &:value`  などという書き方ができます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結論から言うと不可能です。

まず文法上の認識の間違いがあります。
`&:foo.value`の解釈は、
&[:foo.value]となります。 よって :foo に .value が存在せずエラーとなります。
検証方法として`values.map(&:FOO.downcase)`を実行してみてください。`:FOO.downcase #=> :foo`ですから何のエラーも起こしません。

次に、`values.map(&:'foo')`が可能なので`values.map(&:'foo.value')`が可能であると思われるかもしれません。しかしこれも不可能です。
なぜなら`values.map{|x| x.send(:'foo.value')}`と等しくなりますのでundefined method `foo.value'が発生します。

Answer (score 4):

Norikaz Ishiiさんも書いているとおり、普通にやろうとすると無理です。

そこでいくつか代替案を出してみます。

### 案1：素直に書く

無理せず、ブロックの中にコードを書けばいいじゃない、という案です。
僕も普通こうします。

```
values.map {|hoge| hoge.foo.value }
```

### 案2：メソッドを定義する

自分でクラスを拡張できるなら、一発で値を取ってこれるメソッドを定義してみては？という案です。
「デメテルの法則（[参考](http://qiita.com/hirokidaichi/items/d6c473d8011bd9330e63)）」にも違反しないので、オブジェクト指向的にはよいアプローチかもしれません。

```
class Hoge
  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize(value)
    @foo = Foo.new(value)
  end

  def foo_value
    foo.value
  end
end

values.map(&:foo_value)
```

### 案3：gemを使う

[yuroyoro/lambda_driver](https://github.com/yuroyoro/lambda_driver) というgemを使うと、質問で挙げられたコードに近いコードが書けます。

```
require 'lambda_driver'

values.map(&:foo >> :value)
```

ご自身の好みに合うアプローチを採用してみてください。

Comment: lambda_driver楽しそうですね…（お腹抱えてる）。パっと見、ちょっとできること多すぎる気がしますが気になりました。